# Delayload Python3 dll from VC++

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, dll, cpython

I'm working on a program that supports Python extensions and noticed that it does not open if the user does not have Python in their machines or uses the x64 version instead of the x32 one. (I cannot change this last part as it does not depend on me).

So I've been reading about delay loading to later check if the library is available and did this:

```
// linker: /DELAYLOAD:python3.dll
#include <delayimp.h>
#include <Python.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "delayimp")
#pragma comment(lib, "python3")
```

...and everything worked fine until studio gave me this problem:

> LNK1194   cannot delay-load 'python3.dll' due to import of data symbol
> '__imp__PyType_Type'; link without /DELAYLOAD:python3.dll

So my question is: Is there a workaround for this issue?

I've been thinking of editing the includes and directly defining PyType_Type in my program from their GitHub page but I'm afraid of breaking something...

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, as that;s not a function. The real question is why would you need this behavior? Seems like an *XY Problem*. One way is to dynamically load the *.dll* (but you;d have to redefine types and functions).

Comment: I need it to support ".py" extensions. We are supposed to run an interpreter instance and for that linking the python3.dll is needed. 

Yes, doing a dynamic load seems like a good approach but I'm a bit concerned with the PyType_Type as I don't know that much about importing data types.

Comment: It was pretty clear that you'd need some *Python* functionalities, otherwise linking with *python3.lib* would not be required. My question is why delay loading?

Comment: Ah Ok!. Because otherwise the whole thing closes if python is not on the system and since it is an optional feature... I wanted to delay load an check if the dll is present and then enable it.

Comment: Hmm, well there could be a way. Link *python.lib* to a *.dll*, which exposes a (simple) *API*, and only (attempt to) load that dynamically whenever you want to access *Python* functionality.

Comment: Seems like a good alternative. Either that or manually writing the imports at runtime as you said before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small demo (as I thought in one of my comments)

*dll00.h*:

```c
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined DLL00_EXPORTS
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API int dllPyFunc(const char *pyStr);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*dll00.c*:

```c
#define DLL00_EXPORTS

#include "dll00.h"

#include <Python.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int dllPyFunc(const char *pyStr)
{
    if (!pyStr) {
        printf("NULL PY test!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int res = 0;
    if (!Py_IsInitialized())
        Py_InitializeEx(0);
    res = PyRun_SimpleString(pyStr);
    res |= Py_FinalizeEx();
    return res;
}
```

*main00.c*:

```c
#if defined(DELAYLOAD)
#  include "dll00.h"

#  pragma comment(lib, "delayimp")
#  pragma comment(lib, "dll00")
#endif

#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#if !defined(DELAYLOAD)
typedef int (*DllPyFuncFuncPtr)(const char *pyStr);
DllPyFuncFuncPtr dllPyFunc = NULL;
#endif


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    printf("Arg count: %d\n", argc);
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("NO PYTHON WHATSOEVER!!!\n");
        ret = 0;
    } else {
        printf("Attempt to run [%s] from Python\n", argv[1]);
#if !defined(DELAYLOAD)
        HMODULE hDll00 = LoadLibrary("dll00.dll");
        if (hDll00 == NULL) {
            printf("Error loading dll: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
        dllPyFunc = (DllPyFuncFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hDll00, "dllPyFunc");
        if (dllPyFunc == NULL) {
            printf("Error getting function: %d\n", GetLastError());
            FreeLibrary(hDll00);
            hDll00 = NULL;
            return -2;
        }
#endif
        ret = dllPyFunc(argv[1]);
#if !defined(DELAYLOAD)
        FreeLibrary(hDll00);
        hDll00 = NULL;
#endif
    }
    printf("\nDone.\n");
    return ret;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q069418904]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\MS\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 >nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.c
> dll00.h
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .dll
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.08\include" dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.08\libs"
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .exe (dynamic .dll load)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00_pc064.exe
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .exe (delayed .dll load)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 /DDELAYLOAD main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00_dl_pc064.exe /DELAYLOAD:dll00.dll
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.h
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> main00.c
> main00.obj
> main00_dl_pc064.exe
> main00_pc064.exe
>
> [prompt]> :: Save current path (which doesn't have python38.dll's parent)
> [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
> [prompt]> :: Add python38.dll's parent to PATH
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.08
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> main00_pc064.exe
> Arg count: 1
> NO PYTHON WHATSOEVER!!!
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> main00_pc064.exe "import os;print(os.getcwd())"
> Arg count: 2
> Attempt to run [import os;print(os.getcwd())] from Python
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q069418904
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> main00_dl_pc064.exe
> Arg count: 1
> NO PYTHON WHATSOEVER!!!
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> main00_dl_pc064.exe "import os;print(os.getcwd())"
> Arg count: 2
> Attempt to run [import os;print(os.getcwd())] from Python
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q069418904
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> :: NO python38.dll
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%
>
> [prompt]> main00_pc064.exe
> Arg count: 1
> NO PYTHON WHATSOEVER!!!
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> main00_pc064.exe "import os;print(os.getcwd())"
> Arg count: 2
> Attempt to run [import os;print(os.getcwd())] from Python
> Error loading dll: 126
>
> [prompt]> main00_dl_pc064.exe
> Arg count: 1
> NO PYTHON WHATSOEVER!!!
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> main00_dl_pc064.exe "import os;print(os.getcwd())"
> Arg count: 2
> Attempt to run [import os;print(os.getcwd())] from Python
> <<<<<<<< CRASH HERE >>>>>>>>
> ```

**Notes**:

- Although this example is too trivial to evidentiate it, dynamic loading the library requires more code (on the *.exe* side)
- On the other hand, delay load approach crashes if *Python* is required but not present in *%PATH%*

Answer (score 0):

So I found a post by Raymond Chen about dll forwarding. It may be a solution so I will post it here for now and update later if it works.

Raymond Chen post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080204-00/?p=23593

Edit: It seems like a good option for other libs but not for Python. They are already doing this (the python3 dll is a forwarding to python3X) and the __imp__PyType_Type is still a problem.

In the end I just created a copy of the lib and put it inside a folder called PyLibrary that compiles with Python.

Edit2: In the end I may just take python off and into another module and just delayload that module.